# Docker Dev Environment for GO

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

## What I want to do

I want to set up docker dev environment fo Go.

## Code

```
// directory
project(absolute path: /Uses/[username]/project)
|--- app
|  |--- config
|  |  |___ config.go
|  |--- main.go
|  |___ config.ini 
|--- docker-compose.yml
|___ Dockerfile
```

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "app/config"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    fmt.Println(config.Config.ApiKey)
    fmt.Println(config.Config.ApiSecrete)
}
```

```
// docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - ./app:/go/src/app
```

```
// Dockerfile
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOPATH /go
ADD ./app /go/src/app/
```

## Dev Environment

When I run `docker-compose exec app go env`, I get

```
GOPATH="/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

## Problem

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build`,
I get
`package app/config is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/app/config)`.
So, I can't import `"app/config"` in `main.go` file.

I want to know how import self-made package when I set up GO dev environment with docker.

Comment: Use `go mod init <moduleName>` to create a module for your project, and use that module name to import packages.

Comment: I'd just [install Go](https://golang.org/dl/); what is leading you to add an isolation layer like Docker around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [go-env-series](https://www.docker.com/blog/tag/go-env-series/) about how to use Docker to define your Go development environment in code.
Example: [`chris-crone/containerized-go-dev`](https://github.com/chris-crone/containerized-go-dev)

The [second article](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-2/) does mention [`go mod init`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-init), which helps [with import path](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules#creating-a-new-module-h2):

> Let’s make the current directory the root of a module by using `go mod init`:
>
> ```
> $ go mod init example.com/hello
> go: creating new go.mod: module example.com/hello
> ```
>
> The `go.mod` file only appears in the root of the module.
>
> **Packages in subdirectories have import paths consisting of the module path plus the path to the subdirectory**.
>
> For example, if we created a subdirectory world, we would not need to (nor want to) run `go mod init` there.
> The package would automatically be recognized as part of the `example.com/hello` module, with import path `example.com/hello/world`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you, I've solved this problem, so I'll share.

I run `go mod init app`, and `go mod tidy`.

Then, I change Dockerfile to set `GO111MODULE=on`.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - ./app:/go/src/app
    environment:
      - "GO111MODULE=on"
```

```
// directory
project(absolute path: /Uses/[username]/project)
|--- app
|  |--- config
|  |  |___ config.go
|  |--- main.go
|  |--- config.ini 
|  |--- go.mod
|  |___ go.sum  
|--- docker-compose.yml
|___ Dockerfile
```

cf.
[1](https://qiita.com/Syoitu/items/f221b52231703cebe8ff)
[2](https://qiita.com/fetaro/items/31b02b940ce9ec579baf#gopath%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AEimport)